# Trying to get git's core.pager to work on both mingw and cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin, mingw

I am trying to get git for Windows working identically in the mingw bash that comes with git for Windows and in my cygwin terminal.

Right now, I cannot get the core.pager (which determines whether a command that would overflow the screen gets paged) to work on both at the same time.

If I use `git config --global core.pager less`, it works fine in mingw64, but not in cygwin, despite there being the cygwin version of `less` in the path.  In cygwin, it behaves identically to if I have it set to `git config --global core.pager ''`

I can get it working in cygwin by using  `git config --global core.pager more`.  This breaks it in  doesn't work in mingw, since it doesn't have a `more`.

I even tried making a copy of the mingw `less.exe` and naming it `more.exe`, but when I did that, all of the colors from git's output were mangled.  Git must have smarts to know what the different pagers can handle.

Now, I *could* solve this by having a different `~/.gitconfig` in both cygwin and mingw (I currently have a symbolic link from one to the other), but that's just a problem waiting to happen when they eventually get out of sync.

Why doesn't cygwin's `less` work with `git` for windows?

Are there any other work-arounds that I could try?

Comment: Both git and bash are part of cygwin. It is always better to use utilities that are all from the same distribution.

Comment: @DavidPostill, that is in theory.  In Windows, unfortunately, you have IDEs and tools that make use of Git for Windows which must understand Windows paths.  Cygwin's Git does not work with them.  And if then you start playing in a repo checked out with Git for Windows using Cygwin's Git, the paths incompatibility will cause you problems.  This is why you stick with Git for Windows, even under Cygwin.  All your IDE and CLI actions will work fine.  Git for Windows under Cygwin works actually fine, except for the code.pager (less).  As a workaround, I always pipe to less:  `git log | less`

Comment: @HansDeragon That's all very good but the OP made no mention of IDEs or other Windows based tools.

Answer (score 1):

For issues with Cygwin, you could install the missing command using this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752133/4654241

That should provide you with both less and more on Cygwin.

As for making less/more work between a Windows command prompt and a git-bash.exe window, I use less provided by [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and add it to my path.

Then the path that is set with git-bash.exe for Windows will use the default one installed with Git, and a Windows command prompt will use the Windows UnxUtils version of less.

Comment: The better solution is to not use git bash at all. Both git and bash are part of cygwin. It is always better to use utilities that are all from the same distribution.